# build mode - activate logs with a certain level

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using QX 5.0.2.

In Build mode, is there a way to (re)activate logs and only show warning+error (log level?)?

Env key 'qx.debug' = true seems to reactivate logs but I can't find the env key for log level (to set it for example to warning).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the static `addFilter` method, documented at http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.log.Logger. It lets you filter messages by the class from which they originate, by log level, and on an all-appenders basis or per appender.

Derrell